# Are there any ways to deal with the vanishing gradient for saturating non-linearities that doesn't involve Batch Normalization or ReLu units?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I wanted to train a network with non-linearities that suffer from the vanishing (or exploding gradient problem though mainly vanishing). I know that the (current) standard way is to use batch normalization [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) [BN][1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) or simply abandon the non-linearity and use ReLu [Rectifier/ReLu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) units.

I wanted two things:

1. Stick with my non-linearity, so I don't want to abandon it and use the ReLu (i.e. no ReLu's allowed!). Re-parametrising the non-linearity is ok, say putting a multiplicative in front of it as in $\theta(s)$ for example.
2. Ideally, I did not want to rely too much batch normalization (or at least if its used, it has to be used in a novel way other than how it was used in the original paper or generalize to many non-linearities). One of the reasons I wanted to avoid Batch Normalize is because it seems to only work for specific non-linearities. For example, for sigmoids, tanh but its unclear how they'd work for other non-linearities, say gaussians.

The reason I have these constraints is because I'd like to deal with the problem of vanishing gradient or exploding gradients by taling the problem directly rather than hacking a solution that works only for specific non-linearities or just avoiding the problem by shoving in a ReLu.

I was wondering, with those two constraints, what are alternative ways to deal with the vanishing gradient problem? (another non-linearity in consideration would be RBF gaussian kernel with euclidean norm pre-activation, sigmoid, tanh, etc)

The possible (vague) ideas I had in mind would be:

1. Have good initialization so that the saturating non-linearities don't start already saturated (saturated non-linearities result in gradients close to zero).
2. For RBF, similarly, good init might be important because gaussians mostly have a large value close to 0 (i.e. when filters are similar to its activation or data). Thus, having them too big or too small has a similar vanishing gradient issues.
3. I don't really know if this is too constraining but it would be nice if there was a different way to use batch normalization other than its traditional suggestion in the original paper (or maybe some BN idea that generalizes to a bigger set of non-linearities, currently it seems most of the research is to show it works for sigmoids as far as I know).
4. Another idea could be to instead of having non-linearity $\theta(z)$ we have $a \theta(z) $ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a > 1$, then it means that the non-linearities are not multiplied backwards multiple times for each layer, so as to avoid to be "vanished" for earlier layers. It might make the learning rule unstable, so maybe some regularizer might be a good idea.
5. An optimizer that intrinsically deals with the vanishing gradient (or at least updating each parameter differently). For example, if its a layer closer to the input, then the learning step should be larger. It would be nice for the learning algorithm to take this into account by itself so to deal with the vanishing gradient.

If there are any suggestions on how to deal with vanishing gradient other than batch-norm or ReLu's I'd love to hear about them!

---

It seems that vanishing gradient happens mainly because the non-linearities have the property that $ |a| < 1$ and also because $ | \theta'(s) | < 1$ and after multiplying it many times, it either explodes or vanish. Explicitly saying the problem might help solve it. The issue is that it causes lower layers to not update or hinders signal through the network. It would be nice to maintain this signal flowing through the network, during the forward and backward pass (and also during training, not only at initialization).

---

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167): Ioffe S. and Szegedy C. (2015),
"Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing
Internal Covariate Shift",
*Proceedings of the 32nd International Conference on Machine Learning*, Lille, France, 2015.
Journal of Machine Learning Research: W&CP volume 37

Comment: +1 This is an interesting question. Just out of curiosity -- why don't you want to use ReLUs?

Comment: my reasons are: 1) It seems to me that using ReLu sort of avoids the question of vanishing and exploding gradient rather than address it directly. 2) if one had an activation that one believed to be very good at some tasks rather than others, then somehow we are forced to switch to ReLu even though they might not be the right one. 3) ... (next comments)

Comment: 3) when dealing with gaussians for example, generalizing batch normalization is not trivial (should I batch normalize the euclidean norm preactivation? If I do then the input to the RBF guassian could be negative which leads to exploding gradients, but what if I instead I normalize the output of the non-linearity directly, then, we are normalizing something that already had constrained moments, since the output of RBF and in fact sigmoid (tanh) too, are restricted to a small interval [0,1] or [-1,1] )

Basically, it just seems these two ideas could be taken further, I just don't know how.

Comment: Though my reasons are based mostly on hunches, clearly, we need more research or something to deal with all those points.

Comment: I mean, I tend to be kind of agnostic when it comes to these types of questions. It seems to me that ANNs are just a stack of ad hoc decisions and we work through how to make improvements as a combination of hacks to improve computational efficiencies and assessments of how to improve out-of-sample error. I'm not really inclined to say "This is the *right* way to do it" but instead "This is the best among the alternatives that we tested." That said, how would you feel about the softplus function, a nonlinear, differentiable approximation to ReLU?

Comment: @GeneralAbrial I agree that the current line of results might be just ad-hoc hacks we've combined to make things works. I guess my question is trying to push that beyond that and maybe understand things better. Maybe we are avoiding a good questions that we should not. I don't know. It would be great to know though if there is just a fundamental reason that we don't need anything other than ReLus. For me that would awesome result if we had it. I thought it would be nice to have a question take made sure we didn't avoid the real issue, maybe its impossible, but I don't know unless I ask! :)

Comment: addressing your "right way to do things",maybe we disagree on this point but I feel we do have some knowledge on when is the right way to do things. For example, from what I've read using l2 norm regularization vs l1 is very different. If one wants sparsity, there are conditions that l1 provably guarantees sparse solutions, while l2 cannot (for this look at problem 3 in MIT's problem set http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-409-algorithmic-aspects-of-machine-learning-spring-2015/assignments/MIT18_409S15_pset_2.pdf).Sometimes we do know sort of what we want and what we need to achieve it.

Comment: It's definitely a good question -- I'm uncertain if the answer is known (I don't know as much about ANNs as I would like). But in the "right way to do things," I think it depends on goals. If my boss said "we need a sparse model," I'd know to use L1 regularization. But if he said "build the best model," I think I would have to experiment with several alternative schemes.

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading a standard reference on nonlinear optimisation. then plot error curve/surface (in various directions) for RBF. batch normalisation does not 'solve' problem of vanishing gradients it is more of a hack that seems to work on some problems.

Comment: @seanv507 Two questions: 1) do you mean like plotting the error surface vs parameter variable at a time? 2) do you have an references that you recommend?

Comment: 1) yes exactly (in any direction). The problem is that RBFS are too non linear ( I would guess) to be solved by gradient descent). 2) pulling out a presentation at random http://www.mit.edu/~9.520/spring08/Classes/optlecture.pdf see in particular 'conditioning' slide (see also leonbottou papers).  batch normalisation (in my view) is like input rescaling and I believed the assumption was that one is approximating hessian (based on the linear model  where hessian is input covariance matrix - normalisation deals with the diagonal terms but not the off diagonal terms).

Comment: so BN should work when dealing with close to linear problems [ which given success of residual networks seems typical of deep NN applications] problem with my explanation is that BN is recommended to be done after the weighted sum rather than after the nonlinearity (which would seem to be the inputs to the next layer). however some papers have found better results when applying after nonlinearity! (another reference http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/tricks-2012.pdf)

Comment: @seanv507 I've always found rather unconvincing that BN should only be done at the pre-synaptic activation. As you mentioned, if there are results that it works at the non-linear part, I would be very interested to see it! Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Systematic evaluation of CNN advances on the ImageNet (http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02228). Although unexpected I am pretty sure the original authors tried both and found pre-non linear worked better [for their data:) ]

Comment: @GeneralAbrial I never addressed ur softplus function question, missed the first time! Sorry. I don't have strong opinions on it, though, it seems like a function that would probably avoid vanishing gradients, thus, probably making this question irrelevant if one uses it? Though, I have nothing against it in particular. I think its potentially good that its gradient is always non-zero, but seems to avoid my question rather than address it? Maybe there isn't a general way to deal with vanishing gradients and one has to see the special activation function in question.

Comment: Just curious if you know anything about how LSTMs or Residual networks do with saturating nonlinearities. I wonder if they only tend to work with ReLus. In the papers they both specify that the use ReLus but I wonder if that is essential to the methods or just something that gives them a boost.

Comment: @testuser thats a great question! (I think you should post it on the site btw) Unfortunately, I have not studied LSTMS or Residual networks in depth enough right now. Though, both were the next things on my list since they (might?) seemed related to the reason we use ReLus. If I realize anything of value (or even a negative result) I will leave a comment, though I won't get around to do this for a couple of weeks due to some commitments I have.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into RMSProp? Take a look at this set of slides from Geoff Hinton:

[Overview of mini-batch gradient descent](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf)

Specifically page 29, entitled 'rmsprop: A mini-batch version of rprop', although it's probably worth reading through the full set to get a fuller idea of some of the related ideas.

Also related is Yan Le Cun's [No More Pesky Learning Rates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1106)

and Brandyn Webb's [SMORMS3](http://sifter.org/~simon/journal/20150420.html).

The main idea is to look at the sign of gradient and whether it's flip-flopping or not; if it's consistent then you want to move in that direction, and if the sign isn't flipping then whatever step you just took must be OK, provided it isn't vanishingly small, so there are ways of controlling the step size to keep it sensible and that are somewhat independent of the actual gradient.

So the short answer to how to handle vanishing or exploding gradients is simply - don't use the gradient's magnitude!

Comment: how do you do "so there are ways of controlling the step size to keep it sensible and that are somewhat independent of the actual gradient." Does one have to do this manually or is there an algorithm that works that does this?

Comment: There are various methods (and variants) discussed in the links, but they do all provide a method for calculating a weight update that is something other than the product of a gradient and a learning rate.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my understandings, may not be correct.

The cause of the vanishing gradient problem is that `sigmoid` `tanh` (and RBF) saturate on **both sides** (`-inf` and `inf`), so it's very likely for the input of such non-linearity to fall on the saturated regions.

The effect of BN is that it "pulls" the input of the non-linearity towards a small range around 0 $N(0,1)$ as a starting point , where such non-linearities don't saturate. So I guess it will work with RBF as well.

To remove the non-linearity of ReLU, we can use the softplus funtion $\log(1+e^x)$, which is very close to ReLU, and was used in [Geoffrey Hinton`s papper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2010_NairH10.pdf) to explain why ReLU would work.

[image]

Also the residual networks or the highway networks provide another way of addressing vanishing gradients (via shortcuts). From my experience such architecture gets trained way faster than only connecting the loss to the last layer.

Moreover **the difficulty of training deep networks is not solely because of the vanishing gradient**, but other factors as well (e.g. the internal covariate shift). There's a recent paper [layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450) about another way of doing normalization, it doesn't say about vanishing gradients though, but maybe you'll be interested.